# Timing issue with window.open?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var WindowObject = window.open("/cur/cases-c-print", "PrintWindow");
WindowObject.SettingsStore = SettingsStore;
```

However, in the init() of WindowObject, it needs it have the SettingsStore. I believe the following is happening:

1. The window opens, and initializes
2. The SettingsStore is set (we are too late at this point)

Instead, I need to do something like:

```
var WindowObject = new window("/cur/cases-c-print", "PrintWindow");
WindowObject.SettingsStore = SettingsStore; 
WindowObject.open();
```

OR

```
var WindowObject = window.open("/cur/cases-c-print", "PrintWindow", SettingsStore);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't have an example to use, but this sounds like you need to use an `onLoad` or `ready` function to encapsulate around SettingsStore.

Comment: What is `window.SettingsStore`? I don't see it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @Barmar It is a new property that I am adding.

Comment: Hi? I really need help on this thanks. Is my question unclear? Basically I am asking how to pass params to the Window that it requires upon its initialization.